# Can't send emails with pyramid_mailer and gmail

Tags: python, smtp, gmail, pyramid

I am trying to send emails from my pyramid website with my gmail smtp and the pyramid_mailer package. First of all, if anyone has another suggestion for an email solution, please let me know!

I added the following to my dev.ini:

```
mail.host = smtp.gmail.com
mail.username = user@gmail.com
mail.password = password
mail.port = 465
mail.ssl = True
```

And then I'm sending the message like so:

```
config.registry['mailer'] = Mailer.from_settings(settings)
```

and later...

```
mailer = request.registry['mailer']
message = Message(subject="hello world",
                      sender="admin@mysite.com",
                      recipients=["someaddress@gmail.com"],
                      body="hello!")
mailer.send(message)
```

Unfortunately, I get the following exception:

```
SMTPServerDisconnected: please run connect() first
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Not an answer, but can you try it with another SMTP server?  http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.python/browse_thread/thread/4791505038b2fca5

Answer (score 5):

The following settings worked for me:

```
# pyramid_mailer
mail.host = smtp.gmail.com
mail.port = 587
mail.username = my.login@gmail.com
mail.password = mypassword
mail.tls = True
```

Your mail sending code seems to be the same as mine, so that should work.

I haven't tried SSL, but I'm assuming that all kinds of bugaboos may exist thataway.

Comment: One thing; Gmail changes the From: header which is a bummer.

Comment: Matt, did you place this in the `development.ini` config file under `[server:main]` with the server info? Or something like `[app:main]` ? See pyramid docs: http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/project.html#development-ini

Answer (score 2):

The email is not actually sent until the transaction is committed.

You should commit the transaction:

```
import transaction
transaction.commit()
```

or use send_immediately:

```
mailer.send_immediately(message, fail_silently=False)
```