# pyramid_mailer not sending emails?

Tags: python, email, pyramid

New to Pyramid here, and trying to set up pyramid_mailer to send an email to myself:

I have in development.ini:

```
mail.host = smtp.gmail.com
mail.username = EMAIL@gmail.com
mail.password = PASSWORD
mail.port = 587
mail.ssl = True
[handlers]
keys = console
```

in my project/__init__.py:

```
config.include('pyramid_mailer')
```

in my project/views.py

```
from pyramid_mailer.mailer import Mailer
from pyramid_mailer import get_mailer
from pyramid_mailer.message import Message
```

> ```
> @view_config(renderer="templates/site_view.pt")
> def site_view(self):
> ```

...

```
    config.registry['mailer'] = Mailer.from_settings(settings)
    mailer = request.registry['mailer']
    message = Message(subject="It works!",
                      sender="EMAIL@gmail.cm",
                      recipients=["EMAIL@gmail.com"],
                      body="Hey there!")

    mailer.send(message)
```

Am I missing something very fundamental here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In fact you are missing something fundamental! :-)

`.send()` is a lazy-send which adds the message to the transaction manager. If you are not using `pyramid_tm` then the mail will not be sent at the end of the request. The transactional emailing is nice because if an exception is raised in your code after calling `send()`, the mail will not be sent.

Anyway, the way to make your code send is via `.send_immediately()`.

Comment: Oh, thank you! However, it still does not seem to work ): Any other tips, since there doesn't seem to be any error messages which would lead me to think it's not working. I'm attempting to send an email to myself if that helps at all

Comment: when you say "does not seem to work" what method are you attempting to use?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check that and use:

```
mail.tls = True
```

[Can't send emails with pyramid_mailer and gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6799146/cant-send-emails-with-pyramid-mailer-and-gmail)

also you can use `.send_immediately(message, fail_silently=False)`

You'd have something like that:

```
mail.host = smtp.gmail.com
mail.username = EMAIL@gmail.com
mail.password = PASSWORD
mail.port = 587
mail.tls = True
```

In your setup:

```
config.include('pyramid_mailer')
```

And then

```
mailer = get_mailer(request)
message = Message(subject="It works!",
                  sender="EMAIL@gmail.cm",
                  recipients=["EMAIL@gmail.com"],
                  body="Hey there!")

mailer.send_immediately(message, fail_silently=False)
```

If nothing still work, you can enable debugging using

mail.debug = True

It should dump in stdout the smtp session. If something didn't work. You'll know exactly why. If everything is fine.